# ctypes Structure strange behaviour?

Tags: c, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm defining my structure in python according to the docs (or so I think) but when calling the c function the values don't match:

Python code:

```
print(f"SchemaID:{appHandResp.supportedAppProtocolRes.SchemaID}, SchemaID_isUsed:{appHandResp.supportedAppProtocolRes.SchemaID_isUsed}")
errn = openv2g.encode_appHandExiDocument(byref(oStream), byref(appHandResp))
```

C code:

```
int encode_appHandExiDocument(bitstream_t* stream, struct appHandEXIDocument* exiDoc) {
    if (exiDoc->supportedAppProtocolRes_isUsed)
        printf("SchemaID:%d, SchemaID_isUsed:%d\n", exiDoc->supportedAppProtocolRes.SchemaID, exiDoc->supportedAppProtocolRes.SchemaID_isUsed);
```

Output:

```
# in Python right before calling the C function
SchemaID:2, SchemaID_isUsed:1
# in the C function
SchemaID:1, SchemaID_isUsed:0
```

The structure definitons:

```
# Python3.8

appHandresponseCodeType = ctypes.c_uint8
appHandresponseCodeType_OK_SuccessfulNegotiation,\
appHandresponseCodeType_OK_SuccessfulNegotiationWithMinorDeviation,\
appHandresponseCodeType_Failed_NoNegotiation = map(appHandresponseCodeType, range(3))

class appHandAnonType_supportedAppProtocolRes(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("ResponseCode", appHandresponseCodeType),
        ("SchemaID", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("SchemaID_isUsed", ctypes.c_uint, 1),
    ]
```

.

```
// C

typedef enum {
    appHandresponseCodeType_OK_SuccessfulNegotiation = 0,
    appHandresponseCodeType_OK_SuccessfulNegotiationWithMinorDeviation = 1,
    appHandresponseCodeType_Failed_NoNegotiation = 2
} appHandresponseCodeType;

struct appHandAnonType_supportedAppProtocolRes {
    appHandresponseCodeType ResponseCode ;
    uint8_t SchemaID ;
    unsigned int SchemaID_isUsed:1;
};
```

Playing with the structure definition in python I was able to get the expected result:

```
appHandresponseCodeType = ctypes.c_uint
appHandresponseCodeType_OK_SuccessfulNegotiation,\
appHandresponseCodeType_OK_SuccessfulNegotiationWithMinorDeviation,\
appHandresponseCodeType_Failed_NoNegotiation = map(appHandresponseCodeType, range(3))


class appHandAnonType_supportedAppProtocolRes(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("ResponseCode", appHandresponseCodeType),
        ("SchemaID", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("SchemaID_isUsed", ctypes.c_uint8),
    ]
```

Output:

```
# in Python right before calling the C function
SchemaID:2, SchemaID_isUsed:1
# in the C function
SchemaID:2, SchemaID_isUsed:1
```

I can't explain why this is the case, am I defining my structure in ctypes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100%, but I think that this shows the underlying problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  
typedef struct A {
        char x;
        unsigned y:1;
} A;


int main() {
        printf("%zu\n", sizeof(A));
        return 0;
}
```

prints the value '4' using clang/macos/64bit, gcc/linux/64bit.  It is because of the bitfield permitting the compiler to compact the structure.

Comment: I'm currently looking into this, was also suspecting the bitfiled definition

Comment: The enum definition is 4 bytes in my 64bit linux machine (I guess its a c_int). So I see why changing appHandresponseCodeType to ctypes.c_uint is working. But how are we supposed to define and use structures which have bitfields? ctypes lets us define them too but appearently its not working correctly in this case.

Comment: I think you are on unsteady ground with that, but this might be a workable hack:  `union { unsigned y:1; unsigned _y; };` in place of your single bitfield will coerce the compiler to allocated a full unsigned for the bitfield.   The rub is that the "C" compiler is free to update that bitfield using byte, or halfword access, which could leave the other bits in an undefined state.   Your scripting language should thus know to access y via a masking operations (eg whatever pythons notion of `x->y &1` is.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.  A C `enum` is equivalent to a `c_int`.  You don't need to cast the enum values.  Just assign them to `ResponseCode` as needed.  It is odd to use a bitfield for a single bit.  That one bit will still occupy a full `c_uint` (typically 32-bits) anyway.  There will also normally be three padding bytes between the `c_uint8` and the next `c_uint` for alignment purposes, unless you also set `_pack_` as well (must be before `_fields_` if used).  Check the C header for any packing directives.

```py
from ctypes import *

appHandresponseCodeType_OK_SuccessfulNegotiation = 0
appHandresponseCodeType_OK_SuccessfulNegotiationWithMinorDeviation = 1
appHandresponseCodeType_Failed_NoNegotiation = 2

class appHandAnonType_supportedAppProtocolRes(Structure):
    # _pack_ = 1   # if needed, uncomment.
    _fields_ = (('ResponseCode',c_int),
                ('SchemaID',c_uint8),
                ('SchemaID_isUsed',c_uint,1))
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the enum type. I couldn't find any packing directives in the C headers. But it seems to work with the _pack_ attribute. The strange thing is sizeof(supportedAppProtocolRes) returns 8 in C code and 9 in python. I would expect the C code to return 9 (if packing was set to 1) or 12 ?

Comment: @MuhammedB.Aydemir I get 9 with `#pragma pack(1)` using MSVC compiler, and 12 by default.  I get the same sizes for the Python definition above.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using gcc (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1) 5.5.0 20171010

Comment: @MuhammedB.Aydemir I guess you'll have to explore your compiler documentation, or fill the C structure with known values dump the raw bytes to see how it is handling the bit field.  It could be sticking it in a pad byte as an optimization, I suppose.  IIRC, bit fields are implementation-defined.

Comment: Alright, thx for the help will let you know when I find more